# CsvHelper barfing on bad dates (on EF migration with Configuration.Seed())

Tags: c#, asp.net, csvhelper

I have a legacy file of Excel data to import into my ASP.NET application. (I'm using EF and the Configuration.Seed() method.) Some of the date fields are just... not dates. There are about 10 dates on each of the hundreds of rows of data, so I'm not going to go through it by hand. How do I get CsvHelper to just skip (and log) the rows with bad dates?

The closest thing I can find is here: https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/956

My code currently looks like this:

```
protected override void Seed(pmg2_tracker_net.DAL.Pmg2TrackerContext context)
{
    //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

    //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
    //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.

    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    string resourceName = "pmg2_tracker_net.DAL.CustomCalJobTracker.csv";
    using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(reader);
            csvReader.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
            csvReader.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
            while (csvReader.Read())
            {
                var assignment = csvReader.GetRecord<Assignment>();
                var status = csvReader.GetField<string>("Overall Job Status");
                assignment.Status = context.Statuses.Local.Single(s => s.Designation == status);
                context.Assignments.AddOrUpdate(a => a.Status, assignment);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And produces this error message:

```
CsvHelper.ReaderException: An unexpected error occurred. ---> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at System.DateTime.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at CsvHelper.TypeConversion.DateTimeConverter.ConvertFromString(String text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
   at lambda_method(Closure )
   at CsvHelper.Expressions.RecordCreator.Create[T]()
   at CsvHelper.Expressions.RecordManager.Create[T]()
   at CsvHelper.CsvReader.GetRecord[T]()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

BadDataFound() doesn't seem to be doing anything for me. The date conversion seems to be happening at a level it can't deal with.

Also, I can't trap the GetRecord() section in a try/catch for some reason. It barfs, and then the loop moves on, and the thing blows up the load into the database with: `System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element`

I would think a library like this would be made to elegantly handle this sort of thing, so I keep thinking I'm missing something obvious.

---

As suggested, I'm trying to follow the pattern here: https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1205.

I added the Configuration line to my code:

```
csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<AssignmentMap>();
```

And my ClassMap file looks like this:

```
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
using CsvHelper.TypeConversion;
using pmg2_tracker_net.Models;
using System;

namespace pmg2_tracker_net.DAL
{
    public class AssignmentMap : ClassMap<Assignment>
    {
        public AssignmentMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.Id);
            <SNIP>
            Map(m => m.OriginatorName);
            Map(m => m.InitiatedDate).TypeConverter<CustomDateTimeConverter>();
            Map(m => m.TechScreeningRequestDate).TypeConverter<CustomDateTimeConverter>();
            Map(m => m.TechScreeningCompletionDate).TypeConverter<CustomDateTimeConverter>();
            <SNIP>
            Map(m => m.CommentsOnClosingTime);
        }
    }
}

public class CustomDateTimeConverter : DateTimeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        try
        {
            return base.ConvertFromString(text, row, memberMapData);
        }
        catch (TypeConverterException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(text);
            return default(DateTime);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The stack trace shows that it's using my CustomDatetimeConverter():

```
CsvHelper.ReaderException: An unexpected error occurred. ---> System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at System.DateTime.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at CsvHelper.TypeConversion.DateTimeConverter.ConvertFromString(String text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
   at **CustomDateTimeConverter**.ConvertFromString(String text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData) in C:\Users\hq785\Projects\pmg2_tracker_net\pmg2_tracker_net\DAL\AssignmentMap.cs:line 72
   at lambda_method(Closure )
   at CsvHelper.Expressions.RecordCreator.Create[T]()
   at CsvHelper.Expressions.RecordManager.Create[T]()
   at CsvHelper.CsvReader.GetRecord[T]()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I can't break in the Catch. I'm left with the impression that, because I'm calling this from the EntityFramework Seed() method from the `Update-Database` migration command, that it's been "wrapped" in a way that's preventing me from really interacting with the running code. (I've updated the title to reflect this complication.)

Coming from the Rails world, this all seems too clever by half. I guess all I can do is parse the fields "by hand" (re: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-by-hand/).

Or make a separate PS script, so it's not running under the Seed() method. (The question that's kept me from trying this is how to run it "under" the EF layer, like `rails runner`.)

Or manipulate the CSV file into a series of SQL inserts, and clean then all up by hand. Sigh.

Comment: Actually, this issue might be closer: https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1205

Comment: @ChrisWhite and it answer's OP's question. You should post it as an answer with the fix quoted in case that page ever 404s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally broke the fields out by hand, and wrapped them in DateTime.TryParse:

```
    protected override void Seed(Pmg2TrackerContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.

        if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string resourceName = "pmg2_tracker_net.DAL.CustomCalJobTracker.csv";
        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(reader);
                csvReader.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
                csvReader.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
                var records = new List<Assignment>();
                csvReader.Read();
                csvReader.ReadHeader();
                while (csvReader.Read())
                {
                    var assignment = new Assignment
                    {
                        Id = csvReader.GetField<int>("Id"),
                        Vpcr = csvReader.GetField("Vpcr"),
                        <SNIP>
                        InitiatedDate = ConvertBadDate(csvReader.GetField("InitiatedDate")),
                        TechScreeningRequestDate = ConvertBadDate(csvReader.GetField("TechScreeningRequestDate")),
                        TechScreeningCompletionDate = ConvertBadDate(csvReader.GetField("TechScreeningCompletionDate")),
                        <SNIP>
                    };
                    string status_string = csvReader.GetField<string>("Status");
                    assignment.Status = context.Statuses.First(s => s.Designation == status_string);
                    context.Assignments.AddOrUpdate(a => a.Vpcr, assignment);
                }
            }
        }

        base.Seed(context);

    }

    private DateTime ConvertBadDate(string PossibleDate)
    {
        DateTime val;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(PossibleDate, out val))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", PossibleDate, val);
            return val;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}' to a date.", PossibleDate);
            return DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

As a bonus, I also found the trick to launch the process in another instance of Visual Studio, where I could set breakpoints, and find a bunch of little problems with the rest of my initial schema.